# Como usar Google Chart radar?

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Tenho um gráfico e gostaria de faze-lo ficar como na imagem. (duas ou mais linhas)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tenho o seguinte código:

> http://jsfiddle.net/05g2nw0r/

Answer (score 2):

Pra adicionar mais linhas basta ir adicionando valores a cada item do data provider. Por exemplo:

```
"dataProvider": [ {
    "name": "Item 1",
    "value": 5,,
    "novoNome": "Novo Item 1",
    "novoValor": 2
}
```

E onde você define o "graph", adiciona mais um item no array:

```
"graphs": [ {
        "balloonText": "[[name]] : [[value]]",
        "bullet": "round",
        "valueField": "value"
      } ,
      {
        "balloonText": "[[novoNome]] : [[novoValor]]",
        "bullet": "round",
        "valueField": "novoValor"
       } ],
```

[Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/bdweb1uy/) tem um fiddle de exemplo funcionando.

Comment: consegue colocar legenda?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação deles, lá tem tudo o que você está precisando fazer: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend

Comment: blz, só que esse chart não é do google... ele teria algo do tipo?

Comment: Ainda não cheguei a usar o do Google (quando precisei usar, o projeto em que eu estava trabalhando ja tinha uma implementação com uma API de terceiros), mas pelo fiddle que você colocou pareceu que estava usando o amcharts.

Comment: sim, eu estava usando o amcharts, mas gostaria de usar o Google Charts... Já olhei na documentação, mas não consegui implementar nada.