# Google Charts Radar

Tags: google-charts

Alguém teria um exemplo usando o Google Charts Radar?

Pesquisei bastante, mas não consegui encontrar...
Só consegui [esse exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74404/como-usar-google-chart-radar) que não é do Google.

Comment: Não sei se existe o radar do Google charts! <br/>
[Segue a Galeria do Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) <br/> Saudações!

Comment: existia para imagens, e agora esta como (Deprecated) como pode ser visto aqui https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/radar_charts se existe na 'nova' versão ai não achei

Comment: Cara, já olhei a documentação, mas não consegui implementar nada, por isso pedi um exemplo pra ter uma ideia...

Comment: Cara, tem o Chartjs. É uma opção, pois ele possui o radar. Segue: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart

Comment: Procura pelo Chart.JS, nele tem radar e é fácil de usar assim como o google charts.

Comment: Como a pergunta é antiga, sobre uma API que atualmente é obsoleta e se trata mais de um pedido de exemplo do que uma dúvida de programação propriamente dita, fechei para evitar que seja trazida toda hora à homepage como pendente, ou atraia novas respostas-comentário como já aconteceu antes. Qualquer coisa, deixe um comentário se tiver alguma opinião, posicionamento ou dúvida.